# ServiceAuthenticationManager in WCF

Tags: wcf

Is there any method which will be called before Authenticate in my custom ServiceAuthenticationManager ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Since it's only available method that is not inherited from object.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, add a Global.asax file to your service and then add an event handler for "Application_Start":

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // YOUR CODE
}
```

This event is triggered when an application is first called (including WFC services). Check out [Application Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx)